# CollectionView: Changing scroll direction of each section individually

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a `collectionView` with 3 sections. I want to change the `scroll direction` of section 1 without adding an extra `collectionViewController` inside the section cell. Is it possible to achive this with using only 1 `collectionView`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by dropping UiCollectionView into Uitableview cells.
[enter link description here](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `scrollDirection` of the collection view's `collectionViewLayout`.

Docs are

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012182-CH1-SW6

Answer (score 0):

you can put multiple `UICollectionView` in `UITableViewCell` set the `UICollectionViewFlow` and then set the `scrollDirection` example shown below for rough idea.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xKFM.png)