# Make different Scrolls on each section of uiCollectionview

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I wanna to make horizontal scroll on first section and vertical scroll on second section of collectionView. I used `collectionviewlayout` But I can't, yet!

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            if let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            }
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell

            return cell
        } else {
            if let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
            }

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

            return cell
        }
    }
```

I'm working with **swift 4** and **I don't want to use nested collectionviews together or with tableViews !!**

Comment: I think you cannot do it without nesting another collection view/table view in the first cell section. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622322/different-scroll-direction-for-multiple-sections-of-collectionview-in-swift-2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802597/collectionview-changing-scroll-direction-of-each-section-individually

Comment: Thx, but indeed I am sorry for the Apple company if  `uicollectionview` can't.

Comment: @SAt did you find any solution?